# How to extract common code from gradle jar task to a mthod

Tags: jar, gradle, build.gradle

I have two task  nativeJar and native64Jar, manifest and doLast closers are same for both the tasks except the file names. So is It possible to extract that code in a common method and pass two file names as a method parameter and call that common method from both tasks or call that method from dolast clouser.

```
task nativeJar( type: Jar ) {

        doFirst {

            delete fileTree(dir: "$releaseDir", include: "*.jar")

        }
        baseName = 'NativeLibs'
        destinationDir = new File(releaseDir)
        from files(releaseDir + 'jar_merge/signedNativeLibs')
        manifest {
            attributes 'Permissions' : 'all-permissions',  'Publisher' : 'abc',  'Application-Name' : 'WorkBench', 'Codebase' : '*.abc.com'
        }

        doLast {
            ant.signjar( jar: "$releaseDir/NativeLibs.jar", alias:"WorkBench",  keystore: "WorkBench.jks", signedjar: "$releaseDir/signedNativeLibs.jar", storepass: "freddie" )
        }

    }


    // Create signedNativeLibs64.jar file

    task native64Jar( type: Jar , dependsOn: 'nativeJar' ) {
        baseName = 'NativeLibs64'
        destinationDir = new File(releaseDir)
        from files(releaseDir + 'jar_merge/signedNativeLibs64')
        manifest {
            attributes 'Permissions' : 'all-permissions',  'Publisher' : 'abc',  'Application-Name' : 'WorkBench', 'Codebase' : '*.abc.com'
        }

        doLast {
            ant.signjar( jar: "$releaseDir/NativeLibs64.jar", alias:"WorkBench",  keystore: "WorkBench.jks", signedjar: "$releaseDir/signedNativeLibs64.jar", storepass: "freddie" )
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting out the signing as a separate task so that you get proper up-to-date checks from Gradle.  As you have it now, you'll always sign the jar every time you build.  And if you delete the signed jar, it won't generate again until you clean the native jar too.

You can share configuration closures between tasks.  E.g.,

```
[ task1, task2 ].each { task ->
    task.configure {
       // shared closure
    } 
}
```

There are a few other best practices I'd follow.

- Don't use new File() since it makes your script dependent on the current working directory.
- Refer to outputs via the task versus recreating the full path (e.g., what you're doing with $releaseDir/NativeLibs.jar).  Gradle is able to infer dependencies that way.
- Use a custom task class vs an ad-hoc task with doFirst()/doLast().  Since you're delegating all the work to the ant task, this should be really simple.

I'm not sure why you need your particular file names, but I left them as-is.  If they're not important, removing them would make this even simpler.

I took a stab at your example (*disclaimer*: I didn't try it):

```
task nativeJar( type: Jar ) {
    baseName = 'NativeLibs'
    from files(releaseDir + 'jar_merge/signedNativeLibs')
}

task native64Jar( type: Jar ) {
    baseName = 'NativeLibs64'
    from files(releaseDir + 'jar_merge/signedNativeLibs64')
}

[ nativeJar, native64Jar ].each { task ->
    task.configure {
       destinationDir = file(releaseDir)
       manifest {
           attributes 'Permissions' : 'all-permissions',  'Publisher' : 'Financial Engineering',  'Application-Name' : 'WorkBench', 'Codebase' : '*.fhlmc.com'
       }
    }
}
```

// this class definition should go at the top of your build.gradle script else it will through an exception mentioned in comments

```
class SignJarTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile File inputFile
    @OutputFile File outputFile

    @TaskAction 
    void signJar() {
        ant.signjar( jar: inputFile, alias:"WorkBench",  keystore: "WorkBench.jks", signedjar: outputFile, storepass: "freddie" )
    }
}

task signJar(type: SignJarTask) {
    inputFile = file("$releaseDir/NativeLibs.jar")
    outputFile = file("$releaseDir/signedNativeLibs.jar")
}

task sign64Jar(type: SignJarTask) {
    inputFile = file("$releaseDir/NativeLibs64.jar")
    outputFile = file("$releaseDir/signedNativeLibs64.jar")
}
```

Comment: Any idea about this exception While line 296 is   class SignJarTask extends DefaultTask {

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\workspace\workbench\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\workspace\workbench\build.gradle': 296: Class definition not expected here. Please define the class at an appropriate place
 or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. at line: 296 column: 5. File: build_3ps3f1f00ilt6reek6t9f0j4go @ line 296, column 5.
         class SignJarTask extends DefaultTask {
         ^

  1 error

Comment: Probably a missing {}, () or ,.  Since I didn't have a full example, I just typed most of that blind.

Comment: I don't think that is the case because I removed your custom task and used the following task from gradle example and got same exception so I put the task at the top of gradle script and it worked as expected after few small changes using same logic                                       task hello(type: GreetingTask)

class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
}

Comment: Great, thanks for trying it out.  You'll also need to add dependsOn to the appropriate nativeJar task too.

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping and Is it possible to reduce the number of lines of code if I don't care about file names or go with default file names, please put the updated code in reply instead of comments

Comment: I would probably need to see a full example before I could tell which way to go about reducing duplication.  The most obvious one would be to re-use nativeJar.outputs.files.singleFile vs a file(...) path as an input to the SignJarTasks.  I'll leave any polishing up to you :}